# Why are C++ classes with virtual functions required to have a non-trivial copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

According to the C++ standard, a class that has virtual functions cannot have a trivial copy constructor:

> A copy/move constructor for class X is trivial if it is not user-provided and if
>
> — class X has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
>
> — the constructor selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is  trivial, and
>
> — for each non-static data member of X that is of class type (or array thereof), the constructor selected to copy/move that member is trivial;
>
> otherwise the copy/move constructor is non-trivial.

Now, imagine a class hierarchy that satisfies all the mentioned conditions except the 'no virtual functions' condition:

```
struct I
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct D final : I
{
   void f() override 
   {
   }
};
```

From an implementation's point of view those classes contain only a pointer to the virtual dispatch table. And the base class does not have any user-declared constructors, and the derived class is final, so the mentioned pointer can always have a constant value. Given all that, the copy constructor can be trivial, yet the standard explicitly forbids treating it as such.

On the other hand, the conditions of treating such classes as trivially destructible are met. The class does not declare a virtual destructor and uses implicitly-defined destructors.

Requiring triviality of destructors looks like mandating an optimization - implicitly defined destructors should not restore pointers to the virtual table in this case.

But such an optimization goes half-way in my opinion; classes with virtual functions still cannot be memcopied, even if they can be trivially destructed.

The questions:

1. Are there any reasons I did not think of from an implementation perspective why such classes should have non-trivial copy-constructors?
2. Are there any reasons the restrictions on triviality for copy-constructors cannot be relaxed in the standard?

Comment: They aren’t required, thw constructor is **defined** as being non trivial.

Comment: Yes, in that sense cctor still can have trivial implementation, a compiler may still do a memcpy, when copying such objects, the standard does not preclude that. But user cannot.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the language rule that virtual functions are not yet virtual in the constructor.  Fairly tricky to do, it requires changing the v-table pointer.  Last thing that happens in the constructor is changing it to the permanent one so virtual function calls now behave virtually.  A memcopy could screw that up by copying that pointer too early.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are there any reasons I did not think of from implementation perspective why such classes should have non-trivial copy-constructors?

There is quite obvious one: copy-constructor of `I` is not trivial. And it is not final, so there can be other derived classes. So it must be non-trivial and set virtual table pointer properly after `memcpy`, as there could be derived classes relying on it.

> Are there any reasons the restrictions on triviality for copy-constructors cannot be relaxed in the standard?

1) Constructor triviality part was simply not revised with inclusion of `final` keyword.

2) People think that keywords like `delete`, `final` and `overrride` should help avoid most common errors, and clarify programmer intention, not change behavior of the program.

3) It complicates language: 
*A constructor is trivial, unless you have virtual function, then it is nontrivial, unless your class is final, then it is trivial again, unless something else, then it is not, unless...*

4) Nobody though that it is worth writing formal paper for, proving usefulness of this addition to Committee and pushing this change into language.

Comment: Regarding implementation: I do not agree that class I should set a vtable pointer at all. There are only two places where such pointer can be useful: user-defined constructor and user-defined destructor. Because it does not have any of those, it may treat vtable pointer as owned by derived class. Other derived classes should set vtable pointer anyway.

Comment: @ГригорийШуренков *"Because it does not have any of those"* Are you sure? Really? Not even in other translation units? Not even in TU I will create later and link with already compiled units? What if I do something like that? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4bf2d69fe9d7912

Comment: Class I does not have user-defined constructors, I am quite sure. If you change the definition of the class and then link with other units without recompiling them, that's your problem. No compiler today guarantees you anything in this case.

And In your example, if class I does not set the vtable, vtable has to be set by derived class, including D1.

Comment: @ГригорийШуренков It is not. I didn't change your class. I have added definition to pure virtual function (legal, otherwise you would not be able to ever have implementations and interfaces reside in different files) and added some other derived classes (also legal, otherwise you would have to have whole inheritance in single file and no build system would work) Now I have classes relying on that `I` would set virtual pointers properly.

Comment: You may add definition of pure virtual function f, I have no problem with that. But as I said, D1 will have to set the vtable pointer. It should have different vtable anyway, for dynamic_cast to work. So, how's vtable of I is involved?

Comment: @ГригорийШуренков you are assuming that implementation uses pointers to virtual tables. Which is one of many ways to implement dynamic dispatch. There is a possibility of ABI or implementation which uses, say, function pointers and every class sets only pointers it overrides or defines (the approach, which vtable is an optimisation of). C++ committee was always careful with limiting implementation freedom without a very good reason, so I doubt that will ever happens.

Comment: While we are talking about vtable pointers as the dominant implementation strategy, the approach can be applied to other implementations as well. Class I does not own vtable pointer, if we're talking about vtable pointers. Class I does not own its part of embedded vtable if vtable is embedded in the object directly. In this case D1 will have to initialize corresponding function pointer for function f. D1 knows the value of this pointer, because D1 may call it directly.

Comment: But I agree that it can be complicated both from implementation perspective and the definition in the standard.

Answer (score 7):

The copies and moves of polymorphic classes cannot be trivial because it would break *slicing* copies and moves which copy a base type of an object's dynamic type. For example:

```
struct Base { virtual int f() { return 0; } };
struct D1 : Base { int f() override { return 1; } };
struct D2 : Base { int f() override { return 2; } };

int main() {
  D1 d1;
  D2 d2;
  Base b = d1; // if this copy constructor were trivial, b would have D1's vtable
  b.f();       // ...and this call would return 1 instead of 0.
  b = d2;      // Ditto: b would have D2's vtable
  b.f();       // ...and this call would return 2 instead of 0.
}
```

Comment: This is a great find. I didn't even consider slicing (mostly because I treat it like error).

Comment: Well, they may be trivial if Base class is abstract AND have no user-defined constructors (constructors may discover wrong dynamic type, but they have to be defined to do that). As far as I can see it is possible make copies and moves trivial for a subset of polymorphic types: type has to be either abstract or final and have no user-defined constructors.

Comment: When I ran the above program, the output was 0 and 0 only and not 1 and 2. Tested with gcc 7.2

Comment: @SeshadriR That is the correct behavior for this program. The comments illustrate how that correct behavior would be broken if `Base` had a trivial copy constructor or copy assignment operator - one that simply copies the object representation - given the traditional implementation of vtables.

Comment: Thanks. I (mis)interpreted your expression *trivial copy constructor* as one generated by the compiler itself. So, may I know what's the one you meant with this expression?

Answer (score -2):

Trivial constructors means that no additional effort is needed. So for copy c-tor/assigment operator it means simple `memcpy`. Virtual functions as you mentioned are creating vtable, which is table of pointers to functions. So if you'd try to copy memory of D object, you'll also copy its vtable. New object would have vtable with pointers pointing to old memory. This would crearly not an ideal situation.

Comment: I do not know of any implementation that creates vtables on the fly, vtable is created per class, not per object.